# "Invalid status code" when the user is not found in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

I'm trying to make a simple login system using express sessions, but I keep getting a "Invalid status code" when the user is not found in the database.

I want to make it so when the user could not be found in the database, it redirects the client to a specific route. But instead of redirecting the client, it throws an error.

It works perfectly fine if it finds the user, no bugs.

If someone could help guide me to the solution of the problem, that would be greatly appreciated!

**Log in route**

```
//@ROUTE: Log in route
//@DESCRIPTION: Renders the login page
app.get('/login', (req, res)=> {
    res.render('login.ejs', {title: "Login :: Clipit", curSession: req.session})
})
```

**Log in post**

```
//@ROUTE: Log in post
//@DESCRIPTION: Finds the user in the database, and logs him in (creates a new session)
app.post('/api/login', (req, res)=> {
    const username = req.body.inputUsername
    const password = req.body.inputPassword

    userDB.findOne({username: username, password: password}, (err, result)=> {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else if(!result) {
            res.redirect('/login-error', {curSession: req.session})
        } else {
            req.session.username = result.username
            req.session.loggedIn = true
            console.log(`${req.session.username} has logged in.`)
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
})
```

**Bug:**

```
express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead server.js:185:17
node:events:346
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: { curSession: [Session] }
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:282:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:273:8)
    at writetop (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit\node_modules\express-session\index.js:276:15)
    at ServerResponse.end (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit\node_modules\express-session\index.js:356:16)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:951:10)
    at C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit\server.js:185:17
    at C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4870:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4872:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'
}
PS C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\clipit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one error and one warning in your console:

The **Warning** :  `express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead server.js:185:17.`
This is about the order of the params. RIght now they would work in any order. But this also gives you a hint as to what is causing the error. The params for [res.redirect()](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect) are supposed to be `status` and `url`.

You cannot add an object to the params. It has to be a `status code` and a `path`.
You might want to do `res.render('/login-error', {curSession: req.session})` (depending on your views) or simply `res.redirect('/login-error')`.